# cannot import name 'decode_lzw' from 'tifffile.tifffile'

Tags: pycharm

After installing the tifffile package, when I try to run the code, still this error shows up, could someone help? Thank you.

I installed the tifffile package

code:

import argparse
import fnet.data
import fnet.fnet_model
import json
import logging
import numpy as np
import os
import pdb
import sys
import time
import torch
import warnings

Answer (score 0):

plz run this in your Pycharm terminal under the specific project path:

`pip install tifffile==2019.2.10`

FYI: https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/2019.2.10/